# Scala syntax which I don't understand

Tags: scala

I started scala course on coursera, but I can't get one thing here:

```
trait Generator[+T] {
  self => // do this to be able to use self instead of this

  def generate: T
  def map[S](f: T => S): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
    def generate = f(self.generate)
  }
}
```

Why we are using `map[S]` not just `map` in function definition?

Comment: This is how a method with type parameters is defined in Scala. The method `map` has a type parameter, `S`.

Comment: You are mapping a `Generator[T]` to another `Generator`, not necessarely a`Generator[T]`, that's why you need to tell the compiler to the type you want to end up with.

Comment: Because you might want to create a `Generator[String]` from a `Generator[Int]`, not just `Generator[Int]`s can be returned this way. You have to refer to the new generic parameters somehow.

Comment: I think the question is why is the type param `S` and not `U`.

Comment: Coursera has forums where you can ask the course TAs and the other students questions like this. They're probably in a better position to give a good answer since they're familiar with the specific code you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[S]` after `map` is a *type parameter* and makes it a so-called [*polymorphic method*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/polymorphic-methods.html).  In your example above, if you wrote the same `def map`, but without `[S]`, the compiler wouldn't be able to tell what `S` is when encountering it in the remaining method definition.  So the `[S]` makes the identifier `S` known to the compiler and puts it in the position to report typos as errors.

For example, assume a new method in which you accidentally wrote `f: T => Floot` rather than `f: T => Float`.  What you want is the compiler to complain that `Floot` is an unknown identifier.  You wouldn't want it to silently assume that `Floot` is some sort of type parameter.